# Merging two ArrayLists of type String in Java

Tags: java, loops, array-merge

I have two `ArrayList`s of `String` type and want to mix them as follows:

`SPK = [A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,B]` and

`DA= [ofm,sd,sd,sd,sd,sd,sd,sd,sd,sv]`

I need to create some `String` in other `ArrayList` as below:

`SPK_DA = [ofmAsdAsdAB, sdBA, sdAsdAsdAsdAsdAB]`

in this set I need to equate previous similar elements before turning (from A to B) occur in SPK array.

I wrote a program but it adds one extra sdA (I don't know why I can't do such a simple thing).

```
            for (int i=0; i <SPK.size()-1; i++){

            if (SPK.get(i)==SPK.get(i+1) && (i+1)<= SPK.size()){

            speakerChain = DA.get(i)+SPK.get(i);
            speakerChain1=DA.get(i+1)+SPK.get(i+1);
               SPKTrace.add(speakerChain);
               SPKTrace.add(speakerChain1);


            }else if (SPK.get(i)!=SPK.get(i+1)){

                if (SPKTrace.size()!=0){

            SPKTrace.add(SPK.get(i+1));
           //SPKString = removeDuplicates (SPKTrace);
           String S1 = arrayTostring(SPKTrace);
            SPKResource.add(S1);
            SPKTrace.clear();
                }else {
                    SPKTrace.add(DA.get(i)+SPK.get(i)+SPK.get(i+1));
                       //SPKString = removeDuplicates (SPKTrace);
                       String S1 = arrayTostring(SPKTrace);
                        SPKResource.add(S1);
                        SPKTrace.clear();

                }

            }

        }


         }
      }
System.out.println(SPKResource.toString());


My Output:   [ofmAsdAsdAsdAB, sdBA, sdAsdAsdAsdAsdAsdAsdAsdAB]
```

When I use for loop it happens that it creates more sdAs....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sdA...

Comment: @LanguidSquid SPK are speakers and DA are dialogue acts for each utterance; and sd shows that the dialogue act that speaker A uttered was statement.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a well formatted compilable code. It's much easier to understand your problem, if your code is easy to read and if one can easily reproduce the problem locally. And to be honest, I having hard time figuring out, how you produce the SPK_A from those two arrays.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the relationship between the two arrays? is `SPK_DA = ["SPK1+DA1", "SPK2+DA2", ...]` or is it `SPK_DA = ["SPK1+DA1", "SPK1+DA2", "SPK2+DA2", "SPK2+DA3", ...]` or something else?

Comment: @LanguidSquid We have two speakers on conversations, A and B. In DA set we have their dialogue acts when talking. For example in the above example I showed 10 utterances of a conversation between A and B with their dialogue acts. ofm A (hi), sd A(you good.),sd A (how you doing?) and B starts speaking and say "Thanks" that I show it by (sd B). Now I need to know what dialogue acts (DA) speaker A used before B starts talking, I need (ofmAsdAsdAB); and after B talked once again A started talking so we will have (sdBA)...these are all turning points that I showed in SPK_DA above

Comment: I think I get it. The trouble here seems to be knowing the chronological order of the elements of the array on each side of the dialogue...How can we tell from the code provided what the order of execution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            Indicies.add(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < SPK.size() - 1; i++) {

                if (SPK.get(i) != SPK.get(i + 1)) {

                    Indicies.add(i + 1);

                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Indicies.size() - 1; i++) {

                Count.add(Indicies.get(i + 1) - Indicies.get(i));
            }
            Count.add((SPK.size() - Indicies.get(Indicies.size() -   1)));

            System.out.println("count:" + Count);
            int counter = 0;
            int newIndex =0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= Count.size(); j++) {

                String element = "";


                for (int kk = 0; kk < (Count.get(j-1)); kk++) {
                    element = element + (DA.get(kk+newIndex) + SPK.get(kk+newIndex));
                }
                 newIndex = newIndex+Count.get(j-1);


                if (element.endsWith("A")){
                    SPKResource.add(element+"B");
                } else if (element.endsWith("B")){
                    SPKResource.add(element+"A");
                }

            }

        }

    }
    for (String S:SPKResource){
        System.out.println(SPKResource);

    }
```

The above code can give me the answer but I think it is quite inefficient. Is there any idea to make it more efficient?